# Deploy Java web application to Azure with Chef

Tags: azure, jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, chef-infra

I am rather new to Azure and therefore not so familiar with some application deployment specific things.

I was given with a task on an interview: need to explain how to deploy Java web application to Azure using CI/CD approach. Thing that I don't get completely is that how the application server part is being handled within Azure. Do they have things like WebLogic and JBoss? As far as I understood, app servers can be run on Azure VMs (which's done through IaaS), but is there any other way?

Also would appreciate a tip on how this is integrated into CD pipeline with Jenkins and Chef on-board.

Sorry for this dumb question but trying to get into this whole cloud stuff after years in manual deployments seems quite difficult :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

You may build and deploy Java apps in Azure using a range of familar apps and data services as explained here -> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/develop/java/.

Please refer getting started guides from here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/java/azure/?view=azure-java-stable which also has link to this -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/tutorial-jenkins-deploy-web-app-azure-app-service?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fjava%2Fapi%2Fazure-java-sdk%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fjava%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json tutorial that explain steps to deploy a Java web app from GitHub to Azure App service with Jenkins CI/CD.

You may use Azure VM's which is an Azure IaaS or Containers or Azure App service which is an Azure PaaS that enables to build and host web apps without managing infrastructure and enables automated deployment from GitHub, Azure DevOps or any Git repo.

For more information, please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment

You may deploy Java web app to Azure by using Jenkins plugin as explained here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/deploy-jenkins-app-service-plugin

You may check this -> https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/solutions/architecture/?solution=devops
for solution architectures which would help you to understand how the CI/CD pipelines can be built here. Just FYI, one of these solution architectures also have Java CI/CD pipeline using Jenkins and Azure Web Apps.

Regarding Chef onboard or DevOps automation platform for your infrastructure and how to use Chef with Azure, you may refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/chef/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/chef/chef-overview

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

For application in Azure, include using Java, there are serial ways to achieve. As I know, you can run the application in Azure VM, or run it on Azure Web App Service.

Otherwise, you can run it with a container. Like Service Fabric, Azure Container Instance or Azure Kubernetes Service. A lot of ways to choose, you can select one that most appropriate to you.

About how to integrated into CD pipeline with Jenkins and Chef on-board, I think you mean to DevOps, you can take a look at [updates on DevOps and CI/CD support for Jenkins](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2018/09/14/updates-devops-cicd-microsoft-azure-support-jenkins/). And there also other information available to you.